# How to Get Attribute Code By Attribute Label

Tags: configurable-product

Anybody knows how to get Attribute Code of configurable product by its frontend label?

I've tried this

```
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', 'Foo');
```

But have no idea how to get the attribute code.

Comment: This article should give a good overview how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525046/magento-get-attribute-code-or-object-by-label. Take a look at both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please try below code...

```
$attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', 'Color');

echo $attr->getData('attribute_code');
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. I achieve it like this `$attribute = $attr->getData('attribute_code');` `echo $attribute[0]['attribute_code']`